# Report to see finish date of a plan

Tags: rtc, rational-team-concert

Assuming that we have a plan with all workitems properly estimated with story points. And we have a known team velocity.

Using that information, I want to be able to get an overview of when all workitems will be finished, either by which sprint or by date. Goal would be to use that report to plan the project and to see how changes (remove/add workitems, remove/add people) will effect the finish date.

It feels like something like this should exist, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Related enhancement request: https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=199333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see this feature (end date) just for any plan.

I only know about [Proposed End date provided for Formal plan with **plan snapshot**](https://jazz.net/library/article/658):

> A plan snapshot captures the current state of the plan, the work items in the plan and their schedules, the team area that owns the plan, and the iteration that the plan is created for. You can manage snapshots on the Snapshots tab of the Plan view. Three types of snapshots are available:

...

- **Proposed**: This type of snapshot is available for traditional projects, such as projects created by using the **Formal Project Management process template**.
  Typically, a Proposed snapshot is created before resources are allocated to the project.
  The start and end dates captured in this type of snapshot populate the Proposed Start and Proposed End dates, which are displayed by default in the [**Schedule Variance**](https://jazz.net/library/article/658#ScheduleVariance) view of the plan. Only one Proposed snapshot can exist at a time.

[image: Proposed End Date]

But that might not be what you are looking for, since you have resources already allocated, with a know *team* (i.e. group of resources) velocity

Comment: No, its not really what I'm looking for. It's surprising to me that something like that isn't easily available. Estimating finish date of a plan is quite an important feature and fundamental in agile development. 
Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @Fredrik I agree. On the other end, estimating a due date can be quite complex, as in "[Evidence Based Scheduling](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/10/26.html)"

Comment: FYI, there's an enhancement req related to this: https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=199333

Comment: @Fredrik Interesting. I have added myself to the list of subscribers for this Enhancement.